# Vagrant, Chef, Librarian, and ruby_build *without rbenv*

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm setting up a default vagrant dev environment for ruby and I would like to use ruby-build, but without rbenv, because there's really no need for multiple ruby versions in a project specific vagrant.

Unfortunately all of the examples I can find use rbenv or rvm or the brightbox ppa. I'm not familiar enough with chef + vagrant to get the json right for the ruby_build recipe, but I know it must be something simple I'm missing.

Here's what I have at the moment. It runs fine, ruby-build is in the path, but it's not installing any rubies and doesn't tell me what the problem is.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

  # Configurate the virtual machine to use 1GB of RAM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', '1024']
  end

  # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ['cookbooks', 'site-cookbooks']

    chef.add_recipe 'apt'
    chef.add_recipe 'nodejs'
    chef.add_recipe 'ruby_build'
    chef.add_recipe 'vim'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::server'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::client'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::contrib'

    chef.json = {
      ruby_build: {
        upgrade: true,
        install: {
          definition: '2.1.2'
        }
      },
      postgresql: {
        password: {
          postgres: ''
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ruby_build::default` recipe only sets up the required pre-reqs. You need to make your own wrapper cookbook that depends on `ruby_build` and uses the [`ruby_build_ruby`](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build#install-ruby) LWRP. See the linked readme for an example of that.